# How to print only one item from a dictionary with a changeable variable

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, game-development

I am trying to print only one key and value from my dictionary at a time and have it print based on the player current room position. Every solution I tried so far, either prints all of the items, all the items 10 times (the number of how many items there are),  or none. I been searching for web for several hours now, any help would be much appreciated!

```
rooms = {
    'Lower Deck': {'up': 'Main Deck'},
    'Main Deck': {'down': 'Lower Deck', 'forward': 'Main Hallway', 'item': 'Pistol'},
    'Main Hallway': {'right': 'Crew Cabins', 'back': 'Main Deck', 'forward': 'Air Lock'},
    'Crew Cabins': {'back': 'Main Hallway', 'item': 'Dog tags'},
    'Air Lock': {'back': 'Main Hallway', 'forward': 'Crews Lounge'},
    'Crews Lounge': {'back': 'Air Lock', 'right': 'Escape pods', 'left': 'Engineering Room', 'up': 'Operation Room', 'item': 'Grenade'},
    'Escape pods': {'back': 'Crews Lounge'},
    'Engineering Room': {'back': 'Crews Lounge'},
    'Operation Room': {'back': 'Crews Lounge', 'forward': 'Control Center'},
    'Control Center': {'back': 'Operation Room'}
}
```

This is the best result out of everything I tried so far

```
for i in rooms:
    i = current_room
    print('The current exit to the room are: {}'.format(rooms[i]))

# output:
The current exit to the room are: {'up': 'Main Deck'}
The current exit to the room are: {'up': 'Main Deck'}
The current exit to the room are: {'up': 'Main Deck'}
...
```

It will out put a line for the total number of items there are. That is only the first problem, the next problem I have to have it adjust based on what room the player is in. This is what I have currently have for players to move from room to room (this works):

```
current_room = 'Lower Deck'
command = input("Please enter your move:\n").split()
if command[0].capitalize() == 'Go':
    if command[1] in directions:
        room_dict = rooms[current_room]
        if command[1] in room_dict:
            current_room = room_dict[command[1]]
        else:
            print("There is no exit that direction.\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print the exits for the current room, you don't need to loop over `rooms` at all.

This will print the exits and where they lead:

```
print(rooms[current_room])
```

Or if you just want to print the exits:

```
for exit in rooms[current_room]:
    print(exit)
```

Comment: I had to see i to current_room because when I do not, it will print all the items. For example:
for i in rooms:
       print('The current exit to the room are: {}'.format(rooms[i]))
    
    # Output
    The current exit to the room are: {'up': 'Main Deck'}
    The current exit to the room are: {'down': 'Lower Deck', 'forward': 'Main Hallway', 'item': 
    'Pistol'}
    The current exit to the room are: {'right': 'Crew Cabins', 'back': 'Main Deck', 'forward': 'Air 
    Lock'}

Comment: @Joe If you don't want to print all the rooms, then why are you using a `for i in rooms` loop??

Comment: @Joe I've changed my answer.  Have a look.

Comment: thank you, that gives me a good starting point! That gives me the key 'up' and when I move rooms it will list out each up, down, etc so now I just have to write it in a way where it will list it in a single line, separated by a comma.